# r exclude sentences with keywords

Tags: r, string, grepl, negation

I am dealing with sentences that are as follows

```
    Has no anorexia
    She denies anorexia
    Has anorexia
    Positive for Anorexia
```

My goal is to exclude sentences that have words like `denies, denied, no` and retain only the positive indication of anorexia.

The final results should be

```
     Has anorexia
     Positive for Anorexia
```

I tried this option with grepl function

```
     negation <- c("no","denies","denied")
     if (grepl(paste(negation,collapse="|"), Anorexia_sentences[j]) == TRUE){

     Anorexia_sentences[j] <- NA

     }
```

and this is not working, I think the no in the word A`no`rexia is causing some issues. Any advise on how to resolve this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a quote after 'denied.

Comment: Maybe `negation <- c("\\bno\\b", ...)`.

Comment: You don't need a loop, `if`, or anything. Just `denies = grepl(..., Anorexia_sentences); Anoreia_sentences[denies] = NA`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, that change seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 4):

The **corpus** library has functions that work like the **stringr** equivalents, but work at the *term* level, not the *character* level. This works:

```
library(corpus)
negation <- c("no", "denies", "denied")
text <- c("Has no anorexia", "She denies anorexia", "Has anorexia",
          "Positive for Anorexia", "Denies anorexia")
text[!text_detect(text, negation)]
## [1] "Has anorexia"          "Positive for Anorexia"
```

If you want a solution that just uses base R, use the following instead:

```
pattern <- paste0("\\b(", paste(negation, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
text[!grepl(pattern, text, ignore.case = TRUE)]
```

Comment: I will try that

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this easily using the **quanteda** package.  To get the character object to register as sentences, you would need either punctuation, or to segment the lines into elements of a `character` vector.  Then, we can use `char_trimsentences()` to remove those with a particular pattern match when tokenized.

```
library("quanteda")

readLines(textConnection(txt)) %>%
    char_trimsentences(exclude_pattern = c("\\bden\\w+\\b|\\bno\\b"))
##              text3                   text4 
##     "Has anorexia" "Positive for Anorexia"
```

The regular expression guarantees that you will match words with the glob pattern "den*", and "no" as a word only (and not part of a**no**rexia.